# How can I insert RTF into a wxpython RichTextCtrl?

Tags: python, wxpython, rtf, richtextctrl

Is there a way to directly insert RTF text in a RichTextCtrl, ex:without going through **BeginTextColour**? I would like to use pygments together with the RichTextCtrl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.** As authors admit in [wxRichTextCtrl roadmap](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxrichtextctrloverview.html#topic17):

> This is a list of some of the features that have yet to be implemented. Help with them will be appreciated.
>
> - RTF input and output

Comment: I have a quick question for you, so that I don't create another thread. Can a HtmlWindow's content be made editable ?

Comment: Editable like wxRichTextCtrl? I don't think so, although there are manipulation methods of wxHtmlContainerCell that look like theycould be used (e.g. add a new wxHtmlCell, etc.).